# How can I determine how many background processes are running in bash and do a "wait" for each background process?

Tags: bash, process

Rather than do a `wait` to generically wait for all background processes to finish, I want to do a `wait %1`, `wait %2`, etc. for each background process that I have running.

I dont know how many background processes my script wll spawn, so I dont know how to go about determining how many `wait` statements I need to issue.

How can I determine how many background processes my script spawned, and then assign a `wait %i` for each of those background processes, for each background process "i"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of child PIDs this way:

```
pgrep -P $$
```

Then, wait for each PID:

```
for pid in $(pgrep -P $$); do
    wait $pid
done
```